# Inspiring from something

Tags: word-usage

In my paper, I want to say a sentence like this:

> **Inspiring from** human societies, we want to do something.

As I searched it seems that "inspiring from" is not correct. What should I use instead of that? Just to clarify, I don't want to use "inspired by", since human societies did not DO anything to us (i.e. inspire us), instead we analyzed human societies and inspired from it. So we are the subject, not the object.

Comment: I think you may be reading _inspired by_ a little too literally as a passive. Most (all?) native speakers will _not_ assume that "societies" actually did anything to inspire you when you say you were _inspired by human societies_. A painter can easily say he was inspired by Picasso, _nobody_ will think that he actually interacted with Picasso, or that Picasso actually did anything to actually inspire that specific painter.

Comment: In *His music interested me*, the music interested "me". The same goes to *His music inspired me*. The music inspired "me", and thus *I'm inspired by his music*. There is no need to avoid saying *Inspired by an inanimate thing, we do such and such*.

Comment: But I want to use it in my title too. Does it make sense to say: Inspiring by Birds for Improving Airplanes, instead of Inspiring from Birds for Improving Airplanes? I don't think so.

Comment: If you want to use it in a title, you'd better say so in the question. Anyway, *Inspiring by Birds for Improving Airplanes* sounds wrong, *Inspiring from Birds for Improving Airplanes* sounds a little better but awkward. I think what you're thinking of could be written as *Inspiration from Birds for Improving Airplanes*. Keep in mind that titles are a bit more flexible. Such titles as *From Birds to an Airplane Improvement* or *Inspired by Birds: An Airplane Improvement* are possible too.

Answer (score 2):

Inspire by can be used in the sense you are trying to use it. But if you really want to bring home the point that you were actively "getting inspired" you can use "take inspiration from".

> Having taken inspiration from the human societies we want to do something.

It's a bit clumsy but it works.

Comment: I also want to use it in the title of my paper. Instead of for example saying: Inspiring from Birds for Improving Airplanes, saying Having Taken Inspiration from Birds for Improving Airplanes. doesn't make sense :(

Answer (score 1):

I think *Inspired by* is OK, but if you insist on using *from* you may say:

> Having drawn inspiration from human societies, we want to do something.

Or

> Human societies were the **source of inspiration** for this work.

Comment: I also want to use it in the title of my paper. Instead of for example saying: Inspiring from Birds for Improving Airplanes, saying Source of Insipiration from Birds for Improving Airplanes. doesn't make sense :(

Comment: if one wants to use *source of inspiration*, it can be *Birds as source of inspiration for improving airplanes*